# Does the order in which you pick up items matter?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Picking up Cricket's head gives you a x1.5 damage bonus. Some other items also have a multiplicative bonus, does that only count on the damage you already have at that point or is it also recalculated for later pickups?

For example: would picking up small rock and then crickets head give me more damage then first picking up crickets head and then the small rock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the order in which you pick up items doesn't matter.

---

If you don't believe me, let's do some Math!

Now, I can't find the current formula used in *Rebirth*, but I think that we can still rely on the original *Binding of Isaac* damage calculation.

In the previous version of the game, the damage formula was something like:

```
Effective Damage = Damage_Multiplier * (1 + 1.2 * Basic_Damage)^1/2
```

Each character starts with a base damage of 3.5 multiplied by a character-specific multiplier, for the sake of simplicity we can use 3.5. And we can forget the *square root*.

Every multiplicative bonus affects **Damage_Multiplier**, every additive bonus affects **Basic_Damage**.

For example, **Cricket Head** gives you:
*+0.5 Damage up

x1.5 Damage multiplier*

```
1.5 * (1 + 1.2 * (3.5 + 0.5)) = 8.7
```

**Small Rock** instead gives you *+1 damage*,

```
1.5 * (1 + 1.2 * (3.5 + 0.5 + 1)) = 10.5
```

You can see that the result is not affected by the order in which you get an item.

Comment: He only said that the Cricket's Head gives a multiplicative bonus. The Small Rock actually gives an additive bonus.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I've added a bit of math, this should be clearer.

Comment: The first sentence is still irrelevant to the question, and the fact that the explanation starts with "in the previous version of the game" makes me very reluctant to change my vote. Also, your square root notation isn't rendering properly.

Comment: You're right, I've removed the first sentence. Anyway I can't find any proof that the formula has actually changed in the remake.

Comment: You're probably right, and even if the formula is not the same, it's probably similar. It would be nice to have some hard info, though.

Answer (score 1):

No, the order in which you pick up items does not matter.

According to this [Reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/comments/2r5r6c/psa_using_temporary_boosters_eg_belial_before/) ([/u/Twinge](http://www.reddit.com/user/Twinge) is pretty widely known around the subreddit and is pretty reliable), the damage multiplier is constantly being recalculated as opposed to being calculated once and then forgotten about, so the order you pick up items won't matter.